# Расширить форму до позиции кнопки

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно что бы размер формы увеличился так что бы кнопка была видимая, делаю так

```
Height = bt.Location.Y + bt.Height;
```

но не работает, почему размер формы меньше чем позиция кнопки?

Comment: Перейдите на WPF, используйте layout manager и забудьте о вычислениях размеров вручную навсегда.

Comment: @VladD,кнопка добавляется динамически, изначально на форме ее нет.
И так как размер формы фиксированный то нужно развернуть форму до размера кнопки.

Comment: @cyber_ua: в WPF это не проблема, см. [SizeToContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent.aspx).

Comment: @VladD, а вот тут проблемка, как я понял sizeToContent для ".NET Framework 4.5" а у меня 4.

Comment: @cyber_ua: SizeToContent -- это для WPF, а у вас WinForms :(

Comment: @VladD,уже понял))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что Size - это размеры формы с рамкой, а вам нужны размеры клиентской области (ClientSize):

```
var size = ClientSize;
size.Height = btn.Location.Y + btn.Height;
ClientSize = size;
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, это оно.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx), Location считается по отношению к контейнеру, а не к окну. Отсюда и проблема.

Делайте так:

```
// ваш this -- это форма, правильно?
Point buttonLocationOnForm = PointToClient(bt.Parent.PointToScreen(bt.Location));
Height = locationOnForm.Y + bt.Height;
```

(украдено [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1478105/276994))

Comment: все так же...
p.s спасибо за помощь, ответ Flammable помог решить проблему.

Comment: отлично, значит, проблема была не во вложенности :)